# asp.net imagebutton new window

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

I have a Telerik Grid. In that I have the following code in an .aspx page. What I want to happen is that when the user click on the imagebutton control it launches a new window to show that image. Note, I have seen some code which use Postback but they are blocked by popup blockers. The control's image is set via codebehind but that should not matter for this question. Here is my code. Thanks!

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="prod_image_main" runat="server" AlternateText="Product Main Image"
                Height="500PX" Width="540PX"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `asp:ImageButton` control why not just use a link?  That way you can simply set the `target` attribute of the link to `_blank` and have it open in a new window.

Something like this:

```
<a href="imagepage.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="wherevertheimageis.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Mike Evans: Although your answer as such would not work for me--I needed to launch the image itself--but you gave me idea to put a hyperlink instead of trying an imagebutton. It works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to open a new window with a javascript function:

```
function OpenW() {
    window.open('NewForm.aspx', '', "height=200,width=200");
}
```

And in your imageButton set the onclientclick:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="prod_image_main" runat="server" AlternateText="Product Main Image"
                Height="500PX" Width="540PX" onclientclick="OpenW()"  />
```

And load the image at the onload of NewForm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike Evan's answer here is what works for me.

ASPX FILE:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hpl_mainimg" Target="_blank">
<asp:Image ID="prod_image_main" runat="server" AlternateText="Product Main Image"
                Height="500PX" Width="540PX"  /> </asp:HyperLink>
```

Code Behind C#

```
prod_image_main.ImageUrl = File.Exists(Server.MapPath("images_products/" + rdr["image_1"].ToString())) ? "images_products/" + rdr["image_1"].ToString() : "images_missing/NotAvailable_RS.jpg";
prod_image_main.ToolTip = rdr["itemtitle"].ToString();
hpl_mainimg.NavigateUrl = prod_image_main.ImageUrl.ToString();
```